# Recursion python - counting vowels in a string

Tags: python, recursion

The following code is from geeks for geeks - [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-count-vowels-string-iterative-recursive/)
When I executed to visualize the code line by line on pythontutor.com, I understand that n is being reduced to 1 by recursing the countVowels() function. However, I don't understand how n increases again through recursion of the function isVowel().

P2 - I also don't understand why step 27 on pythontutor goes back to isVowel() and increases n to 2 when that line has already been executed for n = 1. I mean it should go to the next return function directly `(return(countVowels(str, n-1) + isVowel(str[n-1]))`
Please help me out.

```
def isVowel(ch):
  return ch.upper() in ['A', 'E', 'I', 'O', 'U']

#count no of vowels from 0 to n
def countVowels(str, n):
  if(n==1):
    return isVowel(str[n-1])
  
  return(countVowels(str, n-1) + isVowel(str[n-1]))


str = 'abc de'
print(str[0])
print(countVowels(str, len(str)))
```

Comment: Each invocation of "countVowels" has its own "n". After the function was recursively called with "n==1" it returns to the calling invocation with "n==2".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at how these functions are evaluated:

```py
countVowels("abc", 3) = countVowels("abc", 2) + isVowel("abc"[2])
                      = (countVowels("abc", 1) + isVowel("abc"[1])) + isVowel("abc"[2])
                      = ((isVowel("abc"[0])) + isVowel("abc"[1])) + isVowel("abc"[2])
                      = ((True) + False) + False
                      = 1
```

The recursive calls to `countVowels` must be resolved first, before `isVowel()` is ever evaluated, because Python evaluates expressions from left to right, and from inside to outside (like in the case of nested expressions like `(x + 1)**2`, for example).

Comment: so when countVowels is being recursed, at the same time isVowel keeps expanding but is only executed once n ==1, right? @ddejohn

Comment: Don't think of it as once `n == 1` but rather as when there are no more recursive calls. The base-case is reached when `n == 1` which results in only a single call to `isVowel` which returns its result immediately. The parentheses I added demonstrate the different "stack frames" in which these operations take place.

Comment: Once that base-case is reached and `isVowel()` is called (without a recursive call to `countVowels()`, that last stack frame can be garbage collected and its result is returned to the previous caller, who can then evaluate *its* call to `isVowel()` and on and on up the call stack.

Comment: I'd recommend learning how to trace functions with pen and paper, drawing stack frames for each function call, their local variables, and how things propagate up and down the call stack.

Comment: thank you i understood this part, can you also help me with the second part, the return function for n ==1 runs twice, i don't understand that part

Comment: Huh? What do you mean? `countVowels()` gets called with `n == 1` and then since that's the base-case, `isVowel` gets called with `n == 1`. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, i am visualizing it on pythontutor.com and don't understand how  step 26, 27 are executed when it has already been executed on step 22

Comment: Thank you so much! I solved it with pen and paper and got it @ddejohn